# Pegar novas coordenadas sempre que o usuario movimentar o marcador

Tags: swift, xcode, gps

O aplicativo já esta pegando a localizacao do usuario corretamento, mas eu queria que caso o usuario movesse o marcador para outra rua, o aplicativo pegasse essa nova coordenada.

Segue o codigo abaixo

Comment: Estou entendendo duas coisas. Uma é que você já tem um código que busca a localização do usuário e cria um marcador. A outra você quer que ao tocar em um local do mapa, seja possível obter a latitude e longitude, colocar um marcador e fazer o *geocode*. É isso mesmo?

Comment: Isso, o ideal seria que esse marcador fosse fixo no centro da tela. E o usuario moveria o mapa, o local que o marcador ficasse ele pegaria a latitude e a longitude